# scan drives in windows from Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I am using below program to scan the number of drives in windows and create a directory in one of the drives. It works fine , but would like to achieve the same behavior when running the program from Cygwin , since Cygwin is a Linux environment it gives error for `from ctypes import windll`.

```
import os
import string
from ctypes import windll

def get_drives():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()
    for letter in string.uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)
        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives
    
def create_temp_dir(drives):
    newpath = drives[0]+':\\temp'
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        print " creating ", newpath
        os.makedirs(newpath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    drives = get_drives()
    print drives
    create_temp_dir(drives)
```

Comment: `ls /cygdrive` will give the list of drives in Cygwin. No need to use windll that can not be called from Cygwin python

Comment: yes it gives, but wanted to check if there is any module that can scan the drives and give me drive letters.

Comment: from Unix point of view the mounted drives are directory like the others

Comment: thanks @matzeri, i was looking for some method to scan drives, now i have taken the approach of listing contents of _/cygdrive_ and take the drive letter from that.